# How can I delete everything before and after text that selected by regex? [Notepad++]

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editing

I am currently editing down multiple large text files , and need to delete everything before and after text that selected by this Regex `^NewPage.+?NewPage$`

For example i have this text:

```
V.prototype.Jb=function(){if(!this.N)  
_.k.Zj=function(a){this.H=a;dj(this,this.O);  
var Vi=function(a,b){this.B=new Oi(this);  
NewPage 1969 Q2","Fortran","2.49","NewPage  
V.prototype.Jb=function(){if(!this.N)  
_.k.Zj=function(a){this.H=a;dj(this,this.O);
```

and i want to remove everything except this line:

```
NewPage 1969 Q2","Fortran","2.49","NewPage
```

**Note : i must use regex because i want to edit multiple text files**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

- Find what: `^(?!NewPage.+NewPage).+`
- Replace with: Leave empty
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Enable Wrap around
- Press Replace All

[image]